# Xrandr: How to make two panels in a multi-panel display play nice together?

Tags: linux, xorg, xrandr, nixos

I'm trying to drive a 5K thunderbolt display (LG Ultrafine 5K) on a Thinkpad X1 Carbon 8th Gen (with an Intel UHD igpu) running NixOS and i3/Xorg. This is a display that's made up of two separate panels, showing up as `DP-1` and `DP-2` when plugged in.

I've had some success combining the two panels into one logical display using the `--setmonitor` flag, but it's not working completely yet.

[This is the result so far](https://a.possible.space/xrandr.jpg): though the display is "working" at 5K resolution, the right side panel is offset by roughly half the height on the y axis (you can see the i3 status bar in the middle of the right half of the screen).

I'm using this script to configure the display when it's plugged in. Can you see any obvious mistakes in there?

```bsh
xrandr --addmode DP-1 2560x2880
xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 2560x2880 --right-of eDP-1 --output DP-2 --mode 2560x2880 --right-of DP-1
xrandr --setmonitor LGUltrafine5K 5120/600x2880/340+3840+0 DP-1,DP-2
```

Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: [this Gitlab thread](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/27) has state of the art information and several potential solutions to this issue, including patches.